# Xamarin component for viewing pdf and excel files

Tags: xamarin

We are working on a native Xamarin application. We have a requirement to view pdf and excel files in both android and ios Xamarin application. Can people please suggest about some Xamarin components supported for both android and ios application. Please suggest both paid and free components.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Asking for recommendations or links to libraries, books etc is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can try on Software Recommendations sister site but please read the help section on what to ask here.

Comment: Make use of syncfusion : Excel (https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio) Pdf (https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf)

Comment: did you implement what you need? Viewing is simple for both ios and android but i need to view the excel file and edit it in the app itself without Office,